# MOXy JSON schema validation without using attribute prefixes

Tags: java, json, validation, schema, moxy

I would like to avoid using an attribute prefix, like "@", in my json requests/responses. It is easy to configure MOXy to not use them but it results in schema validation errors when schema validation is enabled.

It seems that when you remove the attribute prefix, then it attempts to validate it as if it were an element, not an attribute, resulting in a "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element XXX..." validation error.

As a brief example, if you have a schema that describes a document like this:

```
<foo attr1="bar"/>
```

If not using an attribute prefix, the json would look like:

```
{
  "foo":
  {
    "attr1" : "bar"
  }
}
```

But when validated against the schema, that doc would fail with a "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element **attr1**..." validation error because, since it's not prefixed as an attribute, MOXy appears to identify it as an element (I believe this is via the ContentHandler.startElement() call that triggers the start of an element as well as validation).

Is there any way to successfully use schema validation for JSON documents without also using an attribute prefix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON (schema) validation with escaped characters in patterns fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739738/json-schema-validation-with-escaped-characters-in-patterns-fails)