# AJV schema validation output ~ (tilde) when there is / (slash) in schema

Tags: json-schema-validator, ajv

The output of the AJV schema error in an object having / (slash) in an attribute name is printing ~1 (tilde) instead of the actual attribute name.

```
{
"abc/def":{
"a":"b",
"c":"d"

}
}
```

Let's assume in schema if c is defined as an integer,

then error would be

```
/abc~1def/c must be integer
```

what should be done so that output becomes:

```
/abc/def/c must be integer
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried double-escaping the key to `"abc\\cdef"`?

That string substitution is a known issue in AJV unfortunately:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739738/json-schema-validation-with-escaped-characters-in-patterns-fails

https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%7E1